# setState Updating all instances of Component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to create a quizlet-learn kind of app, and I have multiple instances of Card components. I have it set so when I pick an answer on one of the cards, it updates the state and display based on what I picked. There are buttons at the bottom to change the card. The issue is when I pick an answer on a card, the state is updated for every card component and `showAnswer` is set to true. How can I prevent this from happening and make it only update the same card?

My card component:

```js
export default class Card extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            option_correct: Math.random() > 0.5,
            showAnswer: false,
            optionPicked: 0
        }
    }

    handleClick(optionPicked) {
        console.log(this.state.showAnswer);
        console.log(this.props.prompt + ' 1');
        if (!this.props.hidden) {
            if (!this.state.showAnswer)
                this.setState({
                    optionPicked: optionPicked
                });
            this.setState({
                showAnswer: true
            });
        }
    }

    handleKeyPress(event) {
        console.log(prompt + ' 2');
        if (event.key === 'Enter') {
            this.props.onFinish();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.props.prompt + ' ' + this.state.showAnswer);

        return (
            <div className={`card ${this.state.showAnswer ? "show_answer" : ""}`} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyPress}>
                <div className='prompt'>
                    {this.props.prompt}
                </div>
                <small className={'continue'}>
                    Press Enter to Continue...
                </small>
                <div className='options'>
                    <button className={'option ' +
                        (this.state.option_correct ? 'correct' : 'wrong')
                        + ' ' + (this.state.optionPicked === 1 ? 'picked' : 'not_picked')} onClick={() => {
                        this.handleClick(1);
                    }}>
                        {this.state.option_correct ? this.props.answer : this.props.wrongAnswer}
                    </button>
                    <button className={'option ' + (this.state.option_correct ? 'wrong' : 'correct')
                        + ' ' + (this.state.optionPicked === 2 ? 'picked' : 'not_picked')} onClick={() => {
                        this.handleClick(2);
                    }}>
                        {this.state.option_correct ? this.props.wrongAnswer : this.props.answer}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My card container component:

```js
class CardData {
    constructor(prompt, answer, wrongAnswer) {
        this.prompt = prompt;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.wrongAnswer = wrongAnswer;
    }
}

export default function Cards() {
    const [flashcarddata, setFlashcarddata] = useState([]);
    const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setFlashcarddata([
            new CardData('word1', 'correct', 'incorrect'),
            new CardData('word2', 'correct 2', 'incorrect 2'),
            new CardData('word3', 'correct 23', 'incorrect 23')
        ])
    }, []);

    const cards = flashcarddata.map((card, index) => {
        return <Card
            prompt={card.prompt}
            answer={card.answer}
            wrongAnswer={card.wrongAnswer}
            hidden={current !== index}
            onFinish={() => {
                console.log('finished ' + card.prompt);
                nextCard();
            }}
        />;
    });

    function previousCard() {
        setCurrent(current - 1);
    }
    function nextCard() {
        setCurrent(current + 1);
    }

    const loading = <div className="loading">Loading card...</div>;

    return (
        <div>
            {flashcarddata && flashcarddata.length > 0 ? cards[current] : loading}

            <div className="nav">
                {current > 0 ? (
                    <button onClick={previousCard}>Previous card</button>
                ) : (
                    <button className="disabled" disabled>
                        Previous card
                    </button>
                )}
                {current < flashcarddata.length - 1 ? (
                    <button onClick={nextCard}>Next card</button>
                ) : (
                    <button className="disabled" disabled>
                        Next card
                    </button>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So far I've tried to change Card into a class from a function component, make the `handleClick` method only work if the card was the one being displayed, and changed from having every card being rendered and having most of them set `display: block` in css to having just one card rendered at a time.